# Chain Completable into Observable flow

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

Suppose you want to insert a Completable in your Observable chain, such as for each emitted element, there is a completable that runs and blocks until it completes, what option would you choose? (here the `Completable.complete()` is just to make an example)

1. `.flatMap { Completable.complete().andThen(Observable.just(it)) }`
2. `.doOnNext { Completable.complete().blockingAwait() }`
3. something else?

Answer (score 25):

```
.flatMapCompletable { Completable.complete().andThen(Observable.just(it)) } // If you don't want it to return
.flatMap { Completable.complete().andThen(Observable.just(it)) } //Can be used if you want it to return Observable
```

Answer (score 4):

In option 2. you lose the capability of cancelling the completable because `blockingAwait()` is not managed by the observable flow.

If you don't need to return the emitted element, there is also `flatMapCompletable`.

If you need to execute the completable but also return the emitted element, then I would go with option 1.